# WebDriver Sampler: Error calling threadStarted java.lang.IllegalStateException: The process has not exited yet therefore no result is available

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
var support_ui = 
JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait)
var wait = new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 15000)
WDS.browser.get('http://jmeter-plugins.org')
var support_ui = 
JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait)
var wait = new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 15000)
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
WDS.sampleResuilt.setSuccessful(true)
```

When I run those scripts in jmeter WebDriver Sampler, it open start twice the Chrome without typing url and throws errors in log Viewer panel:

[image]

[image]

I wonder why it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into your log file it appears that you're using Selenium 2.47.0 which might not support your Chrome/ChromeDriver combination.

[image]

Looking into latest [WebDriver Sampler](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/kg.apc/jmeter-plugins-webdriver/2.3) plugin dependencies it is using [Selenium Chrome Driver 2.52.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver/2.52.0)

Try upgrading your WebDriver plugin, the easiest way is doing this via [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager), and re-running your test. Also double check your code as there are repeating blocks and this line `WDS.sampleResuilt.setSuccessful(true)` is not syntactically correct.

Answer (score 0):

The same code is perfectly working on my machine..

Make sure you have the latest version of  [Selenium Web Driver](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) Support 
Download and [Jmeter-plugin manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) and copy it to `lib/ext` directory of JMeter 
Restart Jmeter to pick up plugin manager.

Now in Jmeter windows Click on Options --> Plugin Manager.. Install selenium web driver support (This will download Latest version of web driver support files)

Download latest version of [ChromeDriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

Restart Jmeter to pick up latest plugins ..

IN JMeter give the path to chromedriver as shown below..

[image]

For more information of web driver sampler follow the below links

[Web Driver sampler with Javascript](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2015/11/webdriver-example-javascript-with-screenshot/)

[Web Driver sampler with Java](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2015/11/webdriver-example-in-java/)

Please let me know if it resolved your issue..